# Python: K-modes explanation

Tags: python

I am using the kmodes python library. Can some one explain what the parameters mean?

Link:
    https://github.com/nicodv/kmodes#huang97

```
km = kmodes.KModes(n_clusters=4, init='Huang', n_init=5, verbose=1)
```

I know n_clusters is the number of clusters to group the data into, but what are the other parameters?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [source code](https://github.com/nicodv/kmodes/blob/master/kmodes/kmodes.py):

```
Parameters
    -----------
    n_clusters : int, optional, default: 8
        The number of clusters to form as well as the number of
        centroids to generate.
    max_iter : int, default: 300
        Maximum number of iterations of the k-modes algorithm for a
        single run.
    cat_dissim : func, default: matching_dissim
        Dissimilarity function used by the algorithm for categorical variables.
        Defaults to the matching dissimilarity function.
    init : {'Huang', 'Cao', 'random' or an ndarray}, default: 'Cao'
        Method for initialization:
        'Huang': Method in Huang [1997, 1998]
        'Cao': Method in Cao et al. [2009]
        'random': choose 'n_clusters' observations (rows) at random from
        data for the initial centroids.
        If an ndarray is passed, it should be of shape (n_clusters, n_features)
        and gives the initial centroids.
    n_init : int, default: 10
        Number of time the k-modes algorithm will be run with different
        centroid seeds. The final results will be the best output of
        n_init consecutive runs in terms of cost.
    verbose : int, optional
        Verbosity mode.
```

So `init` is just the method used for initialisation, while `n_init` is the number of times the algorithm will be run, with the best output selected from those independent runs.

`verbose` just dictates how much output gets passed to stdout (i.e. telling you what stage the algorithm is at etc).